# Accessing Webservice from SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, web-services, cross-site

My webservice is hosted on one domain and my SharePoint site on another domain. I wanted to access my web service methods from client script (in SharePoint). What I am doing is

1. Added reference of Web Service to my SharePoint project.
2. Added an Application page.
3. Created a Web Method in application page.
4. This web method further access my web service method.
5. From my client script I access my application page's web method.

Is this the right way to access a web service from client script?

Or can we directly access web service without any server side code or adding reference of web service? and having no cross domain issues

Comment: You might need to use the header Access-Control-Allow-Origin http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653308/access-control-allow-origin-multiple-origin-domains

Answer (score 1):

You may use cross-domain Ajax with JSON-P/JSONP, it was created specifically for this reason. Here are some references to get you started. If you need more specific examples, please let me know:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP
http://json-p.org/
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/what-is-jsonp-all-about

I also have this image - I'm not the creator - but I find it very useful.

[image: Cross Domain Requests]

Answer (score 0):

try something like this using jQuery:

```
var webServiceGetInfoUrl = "http://MyWebService/Web.asmx/GetInfo";
var params = "{'param':'paramvalue'}";

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: webServiceGetInfoUrl,
    data: params,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(msg) {    
        // do something here
    },
    error: function(e){
        // do something here
    }
});
```

more details about jQuery ajax request [here](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: I guess with this approach I'll have cross domain issues if web service is deployed to a different doamin. Isn't it?